# Why macro with integer literal doesn't work with integer variable?

Tags: c, macros, arm

I found this macro function that allows for me to create binary literals in C.

Macro functions:

```
#define HEX__(n) 0x##n##LU
#define B8__(x) ((x&0x0000000FLU)?1:0) \
+((x&0x000000F0LU)?2:0) \
+((x&0x00000F00LU)?4:0) \
+((x&0x0000F000LU)?8:0) \
+((x&0x000F0000LU)?16:0) \
+((x&0x00F00000LU)?32:0) \
+((x&0x0F000000LU)?64:0) \
+((x&0xF0000000LU)?128:0)

#define B8(d) ((unsigned char)B8__(HEX__(d)))
#define B16(dmsb,dlsb) (((unsigned short)B8(dmsb)<<8) + B8(dlsb))
#define B32(dmsb,db2,db3,dlsb) \
(((unsigned long)B8(dmsb)<<24) \
+ ((unsigned long)B8(db2)<<16) \
+ ((unsigned long)B8(db3)<<8) \
+ B8(dlsb))
```

It works fine, but when I try to an int variable in the macro function, it gives me a suffix error.

```
int i=10001000;
B8(i); //invalid suffix 'xiLU' on integer constant
B8(10001000); //no error
```

Any ideas? 
(also note that I am coding in C on a TI TM4C LaunchPad, if that matters)

Comment: Detail: In C, `10001000` is a _integer constant_.  C specifies 2 _literals_: _string literals_ and _compound literals_.   `10001000` is neither of them

Comment: Code initializes `i` to the value of `10001000`. What do you expect the next line `B8(i);` to do?

Comment: @chux that it would produce a similar result to the final line. I am assuming I can't do this by the responses i am getting.

Comment: If you run the C preprocessor by itself, it will show you the preprocessed output. Presumably, you'll then be able to see what's wrong. Unwrapping all those macro calls isn't something I would want to attempt to do in my head.

Comment: `B8(10001000);` produces no code.  It is as if code was `1;` which does nothing.  So you could do `// B8(i);` for a similar nothing result.

Comment: `long L = strtol("10001000", NULL, 2);` is close to what your seek.

Comment: This is a useful macro that costs you nothing to save binary value (easy to read in some situations) to a variable. An example, `i = B8(1001001)` The good thing, it doesn't cost you any processing power on target but rather at compilation time.

Comment: @hesham_EE what is wrong with the good old `0b` prefix?

Comment: @ajaybrahmakshatriya that would be useful but it only exists with gcc and etc, which i am not using for this.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, it's not standard C. If it happens to exist in the toolchain you are using, it'd be readable but unfortunately not portable if this is something you care about.

Comment: @hesham_EE yes, I realized later that it is an extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Macros do not evaluate expressions!

They do not work the same as functions, as they are a text substitution system, and do not evaluate variables or expressions.

Let's say I have a simple macro

```
#define HEX_TO_DEC(num) 0x##num
```

which I can use like this:

```
unsigned hexValue_1 = HEX_TO_DEC(5310B00B);
unsigned hexValue_2 = HEX_TO_DEC(DEADBEEF);
```

This will expand to this:

```
unsigned hexValue_1 = 0x5310B00B;
unsigned hexValue_2 = 0xDEADBEEF;
```

And that's all fine and good. Now what would this expand to, do you think?

```
unsigned i = 2345;
unsigned hexValue_3 = HEX_TO_DEC(i); // ?
```

Because macros substitute text, not values, it expands to this:

```
unsigned i = 2345;
unsigned hexValue_3 = 0xi; // compile error
```

This is not what you want.

I don't see how you expect that macro to work with a variable, because the preprocessor has little idea about your complicated variables and functions and expressions. It just takes the text and puts it in other text templates.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for explaining that.

Comment: *as they are basically a hacky text substitution system*. They are in no way hacky.